# combine 2 sql statement on single table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've table with these fields

```
table_id    name      tablename   parenttable   hierarchy
1          Staff       staff        1              10
2          Student     student      2              20
3          Intern      intern       3              30
4          StaffCon    contract     1              11
5          Staff Dep   dependant    1              12
```

I would like to combine 2 sql staments based on the above table.
I've the value of 'tablename' in 2 statement.

```
query 1 : result1 =select table_id from A Where tablename='staff' 
query2 : result2 = select table_id from A where parenttable_id =result1 && tablename='dependant'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT table_id FROM A WHERE parenttable_id IN (
    SELECT table_id FROM A WHERE tablename = 'staff'
) AND tablename = 'dependant'
```

or with the above table structure

```
SELECT table_id FROM A WHERE parenttable IN (
    SELECT table_id FROM A WHERE name = 'staff'
) AND name = 'dependant'
```

Answer (score 0):

This one also work for me..

```
SELECT 
    c2.table_id
FROM
    A c1
        INNER JOIN
   A c2 ON c1.table_id = c2.parenttable
        AND c1.tablename ='student' AND c2.tablename = 'dependant'
```